# How to change direction to RTL of whole document in Aspose.Words?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to open a text file and then saving it as HTML using following code.

```
var doc = new Document(sourceFile);
doc.Save(targetFile, SaveFormat.Html);
```

the source file contains Urdu characters in unicode format. I tried doing it like following:

```
var doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.Font.LocaleIdBi = 1056;
builder.Font.Bidi = true;

builder.Write(File.ReadAllText(sourceFile, Encoding.UTF8));
doc.Save(targetFile, SaveFormat.Html);
```

But nothing happened and the text is still LTR.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you use should work as expected. I have tested with the following simple code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Define another set of font settings for right-to-left text.
builder.Font.NameBi = "Andalus";
builder.Font.LocaleIdBi = new CultureInfo("ar-AR", false).LCID;

// We can use the Bidi flag to indicate whether the text we are about to add
// with the document builder is right-to-left. When we add text with this flag set to true,
// it will be formatted using the right-to-left set of font settings.
builder.Font.Bidi = true;
builder.Write("مرحبًا");

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.html", new HtmlSaveOptions() { PrettyFormat = true });
```

It is a simplified version of code provided in the [Font.Bidi](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/font/bidi/) property documentation.

The output HTML has proper RTL direction:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
        <meta name="generator" content="Aspose.Words for .NET 23.7.0" />
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:12pt">
        <div>
            <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                <span style="font-family:Andalus" dir="rtl">مرحبًا</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you still have problems, please post your question in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) and attach documents required to reproduce the problem. Aspose.Words support will help you shortly.